# How to conditionally insert a syntax file within an SPSS macro?

Tags: spss

I have the following syntax:

```
set mprint = on.
define !Together().
!do !ValueMissing = 0 !to 1.
!if (!ValueMissing !eq 1) !then.
insert file = 'blabal\second_syntax.Sps'.
!ifend.
!doend.
!enddefine.
```

It doesn't work. I want conditionally insert that file. How to do that?

Comment: I don't understand why add the `!quote(...)` within the `!if ...  !endif` statement. Why not just put `insert file= 'blabal\second_syntax.Sps'`? When the condition is met the line will run...

Comment: Since we are not seeing the whole structure, bear in mind that !ValueMissing can't be set from the data or variable dictionary (at least not without some Python code) as macros cannot access either dynamically.

Comment: I miscopied the insert-file command. Correct syntax is now shown above.